# Is there a good way to map function outputs to Pandas DataFrame or Numpy Arrays?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matrix

Let's say you have some dataset which contains N records. Each record has M features/values, so in other words - we have some matrix **X** of dimension N x M.

[image: X matrix]

Furthermore, we have some matrix **C**, which has K records, where each record also has M features/values - so that **C** is of dimension K x M.

[image: C matrix]

We have some function d(u,v) which takes two vectors of equal dimension, 1 x M, and outputs a 1x1 scalar.

The goal is to build a matrix **D**, of dimension N x K, where every row contains the output of d(X,C)

That is - the matrix would look like the following

[image: D matrix]

I guess the easiest analogy would be the simple dot product - if we perform numpy.dot(X,C.T), that will yield such a matrix.

But is there any simple way to do this with Pandas DataFrames, or NumPy arrays - and some arbitrary function (as defined above)? This is easy to do with loops, but it would be great if there are some built-in methods that yield the same results.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example? Depending on the function, there might or might not be an easy solution to your problem

Comment: an example with simple input output would be very helpful

Comment: Why doesn't your function work with multi row arrays?  What's so special about a 1d?